Retrieve volume and transaction(buys and sells) data for a dex pool, specifically weekly and monthly data
For a given liquidity pool, I want to retrieve weekly and monthly transactions(buys and sells) and volume.
The dexscreener and dextools api give data upto past 24h but not weekly and monthly.

https://docs.dexscreener.com/api/reference
https://developer.dextools.io/

What are the best alternatives for fetching the above data.
